# memory leak in a chart create/render/destroy cycle

Tags: memory-leaks, dojo, dojox.charting

I have a very basic Chart2d question. Isn't chart.destroy() supposed to remove and clean-up memory? If yes, why does the following code becomes a memory hog? Please note that you won't see any chart because it's destroyed instantly. I am using Google Chrome's task manager to look at memory usage, and after 20 minutes it goes well beyond 200MB.

I know about the updateSeries(), but that's not what I want, all graph properties may change in each iteration (title, axes, plots, data, colors, etc.), so I figured the easiest way is to destroy the chart and recreate it again. And even if there is a better way to solve my problem **I am wondering what's the best way to get rid of a chart and all its memory bindings?**

One side note: if you remove addPlot, addAxis, and addSeries lines (so only new, render, and destroy are left), you'd still get the same, high memory usage. Also, I am using 1.8.0.

Thanks,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js" djconfig="isDebug: true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  dojo.require("dojox.charting.Chart2D");

  runCharts = function() {
    setTimeout(makeCharts, 100);
  };

  makeCharts = function(){
    var chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("simplechart", {delayInMs:0});
    chart1.addPlot("default", {type: "Lines"});
    chart1.addAxis("x");
    chart1.addAxis("y", {vertical: true});
    chart1.addSeries("Series 1", [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7]);
    chart1.render();
    chart1.destroy();
    setTimeout(makeCharts, 100);
  };

  dojo.addOnLoad(runCharts);
</script>

<div id="simplechart" style="width: 250px; height: 150px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, give this a try:

```
    chart1.destroy();
    delete chart1;
```